# Data not binding to ListBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

**XAML**

```
<Page x:Class="ManufacturingWPF.ShowHardware"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ManufacturingWPF"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
  Title="ShowHardware">



<Grid Background="AliceBlue">
    <ListBox x:Name="HardwareList" ItemsSource="{Binding Hardware}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="122" Margin="76,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nodes}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Repeaters}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Hubs}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

</Grid>
```

**Code Behind C#**

```
public partial class ShowHardware : Page
{
    public ShowHardware()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DisplayData();

    }

    public void DisplayData()
    {
         //Datamodel MDM used for ADO and table creation
         //Test is a class used to pass the model and as the name suggest 
         test it

        ManufacturingDataModel MDM = new ManufacturingDataModel();
        Test t = new Test(MDM);

        List<Hardware> x = t.GetHardware();

        foreach(Hardware i in x )
        {
            HardwareList.ItemsSource = i.Hubs.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

}

I'm facing issues binding the data to the listbox as shown in the XAML and code-behind content.
I've tried previous answers without any luck , did my research but apparently I'm missing out something or maybe there is something I don't quite understand.
Itemsource as the name suggest should bind to the source of where my data is being held. In this case the source would be my class Hardware that holds data for Nodes, date , hubs etc etc.
And in the textblock I manually bind these properties and display the values.
But this is not working. 
P.S. My DB table is populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the ItemsSource is an IEnumerable and you assign to it the list of hardware itself. So you code should look something like this :

```
ManufacturingDataModel MDM = new ManufacturingDataModel();
Test t = new Test(MDM);

 List<Hardware> x = t.GetHardware();
 HardwareList.ItemsSource = x;

//or
foreach (Hardware h in x)
  HardwareList.Items.Add(h);
```

Comment: Kind regards for the answer. It worked . Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This code seems wrong

```
foreach(Hardware i in x )
{
    HardwareList.ItemsSource = i.Hubs.ToString();
}
```

Then ItemsSource for Binding has to be a Collection (`List`, `ObservableCollecion`, `IEnumerable<>` ...).

Try `HardwareList.ItemsSource = x;` and remove the `foreach loop`

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Hey. It did work in line with the answer above. Thank you for your time and answer!

Comment: If this or the other answer (or both) helped you, you can upvote it/them. Happy codding!